# Setting the content of a pandas DataFrame cell based on the values of other columns cells

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame df with the following content:

```
Serial N       voltage       current    average
   B              10            2
   B              10            2
   C              12            0.7
   D              40            0.5
   .               .             .
   AB             10             3
   AB             10             3
```

I would like to have the column "average" have the the average of the column current for which they have the same voltage. Otherwise they should keep the same value of the current. For example, I would like my dataFrame to have something like this.

```
Serial N       voltage       current    average
   B              10            2          2.5
   B              10            2          2.5
   C              12            0.7        0.7
   D              40            0.5        0.5
   .               .             .
   AB             10             3         2.5
   AB             10             3         2.5
```

The Serial N column B and AB have the same voltage, therefore, their average contains average of each of the Serial N with the same voltage. How can I tackle  this problem without using a loop if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas `groupby` function to get the averages. You then need to merge it with the rest of the data frame. Have a look at the result of each line to see what it does.

```
averages = df.groupby('voltage').mean()
# rename the column so it's obvious what it is
averages.columns = ['average current']
averages = averages.reset_index()
df = df.merge(averages, how='left', on='voltage')
```

Have a look at the [documentation on grouping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), it should give you some hints for problems like this

Comment: How do I put back the average to the original dataFrame as they no longer have the same format? Do I need to use a for loop for that?